# How to add the center divider using material UI in react JS given in the picture below?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[Screenshot of the problem, Divider between the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCFQ.jpg)

Comment: It is just a vertical div with padding.

Comment: I am not able to add that line inbetween